# Jquery Ajax, not working in Internet explorer

Tags: asp.net, ajax, wcf, jquery

I'm trying to do some jQuery ajax and it works in Firfox and Chrome, but not in internet explorer 9.

The final code will have to go across sub-domains, and this doesn't work in ie with the default transport.

So I'm trying to create a custom transport to use in internet explorer

**Method 1**

```
$.ajaxTransport("+*", function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
    if (jQuery.browser.msie && window.XDomainRequest) {
        var xdr;
        return {
            send: function (headers, completeCallback) {
                // Use Microsoft XDR
                xdr = new XDomainRequest();
                xdr.open("get", options.url);
                xdr.onload = function () {
                    if (this.contentType.match(/\/xml/)) {
                        var dom = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                        dom.async = false;
                        dom.loadXML(this.responseText);
                        completeCallback(200, "success", [dom]);
                    } else {
                        completeCallback(200, "success", [this.responseText]);
                    }
                };
                xdr.ontimeout = function () {
                    completeCallback(408, "error", ["The request timed out."]);
                };
                xdr.onerror = function () {
                    completeCallback(404, "error", ["The requested resource could not be found."]);
                };
                xdr.send();
            },
            abort: function () {
                if (xdr) xdr.abort();
            }
        };
    }
});
```

I've created a simple sample page to demonstrate the first technique here:
http://services.whygo.net/sendAjax.htm

**Please note if you use the custom transport the normal transport will then fail unless you refresh**

The idea comes from here:
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/cross-domain-ajax-and-ie#14737000002203097

This give no error message other than 'error' inside the 'error' method called on $ajax, when it fails. I do get a 405 Method not allowed on the 'Network' tab of if dev tools, but the server side stuff does execute.

**Method 2**
I have also tried another method as described here:
[Cross-subdomain AJAX works in Chrome, not IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143226/cross-subdomain-ajax-works-in-chrome-not-ie)

```
if ('XDomainRequest' in window && window.XDomainRequest !== null) {

    // override default jQuery transport
    jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr = function() {
        try { return new XDomainRequest(); }
        catch(e) { }
     };
}
```

This can be found here:
http://www.whygo.net/sendAjax2.html

On this one I actually get 200 codes on the 'network' tab of ie dev tools, but doesn't call the 'error' or the 'success' pararm of $ajax.

If I put a timeout on this second one, then it returns to the 'error' function with a message of 'timeout'.

Comment: Do you get any kind of error message?

Comment: @ExplosionPills no I don't get any usefull error messages.

Comment: Are you trying invoke a cross domain WCF REST Service via jquery ?

Answer (score 3):

Here's the solution I went with after about a day of struggling with this inconsistency...

```
// new method as to not overwrite jQuery's defaults
var cors = (window.XDomainRequest) ? function(url, callback) {

    var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
    xdr.open('get', url);
    xdr.onload = function() { callback(xdr.responseText); }
    xdr.send();

} : $.get; // else, use jQuery's method
```

Use...

```
cors(url, function(msg) { alert(msg); }); // pretty well same as $.get
```

Copy and paste, this of course doesn't serve all purposes, but it's a start and it works.

Answer (score 1):

On the http://services.whygo.net/sendAjax2.html page, I see that you've got the expected `dataType` of the AJAX response coming back from the server as JSON, but the response actually comes back as a plain text string ("Email successfully sent.").

Perhaps you could try commenting out `dataType` and let jQuery figure out what type of response comes back.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the suggestion, I tried that and it didn't help, it still doesn't return to the 'success' or 'error' functions